# How do I get my link to hit the correct controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have a has_many, through association between videos and topics with topicables as the independent resource. I want to have a link that **deletes that specific topicable record aka the association and NOT the video NOR the topic.**

I have this method in my topicables controller:

```
def destroy
  @topicable = Topicable.find(params[:id])
  @topicable.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to @video}
    format.js
  end
end
```

I want to call the above method with this link in my video show view:

```
<%= link_to "x", @topicable, :method => :delete, :class => 'topic_delete' %>
```

However, this does not do what I want it to do. Instead, it seems to hit the videos controller delete action and delete both the video AND the associations, rather than just the associations, which is what I want. These are the logs:

```
Started POST "/videos/468" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Apr 01 19:15:07 -0700 2011
  Processing by VideosController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"F2uF4FDDSPw+jHHGtsosGLjHwkDUg/nre5u+WEPPDUY=", "id"=>"468"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 57 LIMIT 1
  Video Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."id" = 468 AND ("videos".user_id = 57) ORDER BY videos.rank_sum DESC LIMIT 1
  Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT * FROM "genres" INNER JOIN "genres_videos" ON "genres".id = "genres_videos".genre_id WHERE ("genres_videos".video_id = 468 )
  Topicable Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "topicables".* FROM "topicables" WHERE ("topicables".video_id = 468)
  AREL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "topicables" WHERE "topicables"."id" = 93
  AREL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "topicables" WHERE "topicables"."id" = 94
  AREL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."id" = 468
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/videos
Completed 302 Found in 181ms
```

How do I fix this problem?

Here's the video model:

```
validates :video_url, :presence => true
validates :title, :presence => true

belongs_to :user 
has_many :video_votes
has_many :voted_users, :through => :video_votes, :source => :user
has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
has_many :topicables, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :topics, :through => :topicables

attr_accessor :topic_names
after_save :assign_topics
before_update :update_rank_sum
default_scope order('videos.rank_sum DESC')

def assign_topics
  if @topic_names
    self.topics << @topic_names.map do |name|
      Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    end
  end
end
```

Topicable model:

```
belongs_to :video
belongs_to :topic
```

Comment: could you post the topicable model as well?

Comment: is this really that difficult of a question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `@topicable` is of a `Video` object then it will go to the `VideosController`. You need to set the path manually:

```
<%= link_to "x", topicable_path(@topicable), ... %>
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TopicablesController#destroy

Couldn't find Topicable with ID=474`  This is the id of the video and not the id of the topic I want to delete...